# Am I over-explaining or being condescending to the reader?

Tags: fiction, creative-writing

I have many moments like this when the protagonist talks about the strangeness of her situation. Am I over-explaining or being condescending to the reader's intelligence? I like saying, "You know what. I'm going to tell you directly how strange this is in case you didn't get it"?

Or should I just leave it?

> I let out a sigh. So that was it. Back to Prescription 101. I was so unmotivated, though, that even suicide seemed like a tedious and burdensome task. Imagine that. Not even having the motivation to kill yourself. I decided to postpone it for next week.

And another example:

> Again, I couldn’t sleep. As soon as I closed my eyes, the image of the planets came to my head; three silent giants moving closer and closer to the Earth. How did this happen? Only a few hours ago Markus and I had been in a trip. Now we were dealing with an oncoming apocalypse.

Comment: I'd say definitely delete the first bold part. It is telling me what to think, instead of evoking that thought in me (and giving me the freedom to think otherwise). The second contains information (Markus, trip, apocalypse) that might be necessary, but could be communicated more elegantly than by answering a question-to-self. I find "How did this happen?" annoying, when I read it.

Comment: If the intended reader is an adult, yes. (IMO). Talking directly to the reader like this can work, but you have to be quite careful. "Reader, I married him" works in a way that "Imagine that", doesn't, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you are over-explaining. If you want to get into the mind of a first-person protagonist, you have to sometimes write exactly how they feel. Here he feels like he's being sarcastic because he himself realises the absurdity of what he just thought.

That being said, there's a few tiny tweaks you could make (or I would make):

> I let out a sigh. So that was it, hey? Back to *Prescription 101* it seems, though I was so unmotivated. Even suicide seemed like a tedious and burdensome task. Imagine that, not even having the motivation to kill yourself. I decided I would postpone that until next week.